# How can I get the initial communalities for an exploratory factor analysis in R?

Tags: r, factor-analysis

I would like to obtain the initial communalities for an exploratory factor analysis in R
(that is, the R squared of each item when predicted by the other items included in the analysis).

Is there a way to do this with either jmv::efa or psych::fa  ?

I only see the uniqueness, which informs me of the communalities AFTER factor extraction (1-uniqueness)...

Thank you for your consideration : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you note, the initial communalities in a factor analysis are the squared multiple correlations (SMC) of each variable by the remaining variables.  Using the built-in `attitude` dataset as an example they are easily calculated without additional packages via:

```
1 - 1 / diag(solve(cor(attitude)))

    rating complaints privileges   learning     raises   critical    advance 
 0.7326020  0.7700868  0.3831176  0.6194561  0.6770498  0.1881465  0.5186447
```

The `psych` package includes the `smc()` function for convenience:

```
psych::smc(attitude)

    rating complaints privileges   learning     raises   critical    advance 
 0.7326020  0.7700868  0.3831176  0.6194561  0.6770498  0.1881465  0.5186447
```

Comment: Interesting. I like the shorthand version of that.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

### Dataset

Here is the dput for the data I am using, hereafter called `hwk`:

```
hwk <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 
2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 
1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 
1, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3), format.spss = "F8.0"), 
    V2 = structure(c(4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
    3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 
    3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 
    2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 
    4, 4, 3), format.spss = "F8.0"), V3 = structure(c(4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), format.spss = "F8.0"), 
    V4 = structure(c(4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4, 
    2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 
    2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 4, 3, 1, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 4, 
    4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 3, 
    4, 2, 2), format.spss = "F8.0"), V5 = structure(c(3, 3, 3, 
    4, 3, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 
    3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 
    2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3), format.spss = "F8.0"), 
    V6 = structure(c(4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 
    4, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 
    3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 
    4, 4, 4), format.spss = "F8.0"), V7 = structure(c(4, 4, 2, 
    4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 
    4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    1, 4, 3, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 
    4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3), format.spss = "F8.0"), 
    V8 = structure(c(4, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 
    4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 
    3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 
    1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 
    3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 
    1, 3, 4), format.spss = "F8.0"), V9 = structure(c(4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 
    3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), format.spss = "F8.0"), 
    V10 = structure(c(4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 
    4, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 1, 4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 
    3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 
    4, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 
    4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 1, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 
    2, 4, 4, 3), format.spss = "F8.0"), V11 = structure(c(3, 
    3, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
    2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 
    1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 3), format.spss = "F8.0"), 
    V12 = structure(c(4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 
    3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 
    3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 
    4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    3, 2, 3, 4), format.spss = "F8.0")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -93L))
```

### EFA

I did some research after my initial answer and it appears that there is a package for this called EFA Tools. There is a function called `EFA` that allows you to specify that you want the initial communalities. First, run the library and the EFA itself below:

```
# Load EFA Tools library:
library(EFAtools)

# Run EFA:
hwkfa <- EFA(hwk,
    n_factors = 3,
    start_method = "psych",
    method = "PAF",
    rotation = "promax",
    init_comm = "smc", # selected initial communalities
    type = "SPSS")
```

### Obtaining initial communalities:

Then from there you can simply select the initial communalities by using the following code:

```
hwkfa$h2_init
```

Which gives you the following vector of output:

```
       V1        V2        V3        V4        V5        V6        V7 
0.8034001 0.5583605 0.5487691 0.3255253 0.5685402 0.4643686 0.5227481 
       V8        V9       V10       V11       V12 
0.8050573 0.3474202 0.5564858 0.3496354 0.3783390
```

I ran the same thing in SPSS and got matching values:

[image]

Comment: I thank you for your time.  I am however trying to get the initial communalities (the ones that are given in your post are the communalities after factor extraction).   SPSS provides the initial communalities routinely and I was hoping that R could do the same....  Many thanks. Genevieve

Comment: I have changed my answer to fit what you were looking for. Please take a look and let me know what you think.

Comment: That would have worked too!  Thank you so much for your time and answers. Most sincerely.

Comment: No problem! I learned as well.